# Weight of gas dryer drum? Kenmore 87071110

Tags: dryer

In order to repair my dryer I have to remove the drum. As a senior citizen I have difficulty lifting things that are over 25 pounds. I can’t find dryer drum weight listed anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the exact weight, but I'm pretty sure it's well under 25 pounds.  That being said, it's quite large, so you're going to have to hold it at arm's length, which will make it feel heavier.  You'll also need to be able to reach deep inside the dryer to deal with the drum belt.  So, you may consider getting some help with this job if you aren't as limber as you used to be.  You can always try it and stop if you decide it's too much.

Comment: I concur on the weight. It's not very heavy at all, but bulky. It can be tricky getting the rollers to align when returning the drum as well.